# Array Required But String Found error

Tags: arrays, string, initialization

```
for(int x=0;x<n;x++){
BT[x]=0;
WT[x]=0;
JB[x]=0; 
s1[x]=" ";
s2[x]=" ";
}
```

I cannot initialize the string s1 and s2 it gives me error Array Required But String Found error.

```
int n,BT[],WT[],JB[];
String s1[];
String s2[];
String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter no of process");
//System.out.println("Enter no of process");
n=Integer.parseInt(s);//sc.nextInt();
BT=new int[n+1];
WT=new int[n+1];
JB=new int[n+1];
s1=new String[n+1];
s2=new String[n+1];
```

This is the code that sets the array size of s1 and s2

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! the strings were not passed to the class below. dumb mistake